# Hostgator issue with curl: SSL connect error, error no: 35

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to send curl request to another domain, returns

> ssl connection error with error no. 35 on hostgator.

**Code:**

```
$url= $endpoint . "?".http_build_query($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);


$res = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl))
{
    echo curl_errno($curl);
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

This issue is specific to hostgator

Please let me know how can I get rid of the ssl error

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://serverfault.com/a/642203

Comment: what does $data contains?

Comment: yup @Perry is right, ask Hostgator to upgrade their ancient nss package, wait for customer support to say "sorry no can do", then find a better webhost.

Comment: @RohanKhude it is array to be converted to get string

Comment: use boolean value instead of `0` or `1` in place of $value field

Answer (score 0):

**Use boolean value instead of `0` or `1` in place of $value field**

**Syntax**  - `bool curl_setopt ( resource $ch , int $option , mixed $value )`

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

> **Note:**
>
> Better use the
>   default(CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT). Setting it to CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv2
>   or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv2 is very dangerous given the known
>   vulnerabilities in SSLv2 and SSLv3.

**Reference**:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Not working either, it seems server error from host gator, can you provide server related answer which will help me to get actual solution.

I have disabled ssl verify then why it is still giving me same error